# xmltask in java 1.7?

Tags: java, ant, xmltask

Right now I am working on XMLTask using java 1.6. It is working fine with 1.6 but when I change from 1.6 to 1.7, it is throwing the following error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?  Do you get stack exceptions?  Do you get errors?  Please be more specific.

Comment: this the fail that I get
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI

Comment: try including xalan.jar and check you can download it from here  http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI

Comment: In jdk 1.6 it's work fine. In jdk 1.7 it's file ,I look in the lib dir of Jdk 1.7 and I have the the the jar xalan.jar under the rt.jar

Comment: This is the code that I rty to run:
<xmltask source="c:\temp\111.xml"  preservetype="true" failWithoutMatch="false">
 <copy path="upgrades/*/*/@container='admin'" property="if_exsit_admin" attrValue="true" />
</xmltask>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue.  I resolved it by adding xalan (specifically xalan-2.7.1.jar - there may be newer versions but that's what I had on hand) to the classpath when defining the taskdef:

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib/xmltask-v1.13.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${basedir}/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

This seemed to make things work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott It's work great, I also add serializer.jar

Answer (score 2):

Replacing an older version of XMLTask with version 1.16 solved this problem for me.

With version 1.16, there's no need to add any Xalan Jar files to the classpath.